# Como fazer Update em um DB Sqlite3 com POO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, sqlite, pyqt-5

Eu tenho um programa de cadastro de produtos com tudo funcionando só me falta o update, eu conseguir fazer o update editar os dados na tabela e no banco porém não está funcionando direito.

Ele edita todos os dados e não apenas o dado que eu quero. Se eu digitar o nome e deixar o resto em branco ele muda o nome e apaga os outros campos.

Então minha questão é o que devo mudar nessa função pra ele funcionar editando apenas o campo selecionado?

```
    def editarProd(self):
        self.banco = sqlite3.connect('Vendas.db')
        self.cursor = banco.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM Produtos"
        result = self.banco.execute(query)
        for row_number in enumerate(result):
            if row_number[0] == self.listaprodutos.currentRow():
                data = row_number[1]
                Nome = data[0]
                Nome2 = self.produtotext.text()
                Quant2 = self.estoquetext.text()
                Valor2 = self.precocustotext.text()
                Preco2 = self.precovendatext.text()
                Forn2 = self.fornecedorcomboBox.currentText()
                self.banco.execute(f"UPDATE Produtos SET Nome='{Nome2}', Quant='{Quant2}', Valor='{Valor2}', Preco='{Preco2}', Forn='{Forn2}' WHERE Nome='{Nome}'")
                self.banco.commit()
                self.LoadDatabase()
```

se quiserem ver o codigo completo ta todo comentado

https://pastebin.com/ZdHgqkUG

Comment: Nao viu que ja foi resolvida? Olha as respostas tem nada de pendente ou ampla demais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema deve ser no comando sql

dá um print() no comando e veja o que está sendo enviado

Seu comand sql está atualizando todos os campos

```
UPDATE 
Produtos 

SET 
Nome='{Nome2}', 
Quant='{Quant2}', 
Valor='{Valor2}', 
Preco='{Preco2}', 
Forn='{Forn2}' 

WHERE 
Nome='{Nome}'
```

Você tem duas alternativas

1. Mantendo o código, mas você deve trazer todos os campos e depois atualiza-lo
2. A outra opção e fazer um update somente do campo que ira utilizar, neste caso se o campo estiver vazio, você não ira trabalhar com ele;

insira o código aqui

```
UPDATE 
Produtos 

SET 
Nome='{Nome2}' 

WHERE 
Nome='{Nome}'
```

Faça uma cópia do seu banco 'Vendas.db'
Faça testes sql antes de introduzir no código
No site abaixo, você pode testa seus comandos online
http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/examples/GUI/

Comment: Sua resposta me mostrou o caminho

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema adicionando os mais codigos a função.

segue função corrigida

```
    def editarProd(self):
        self.banco = sqlite3.connect('Vendas.db')
        self.cursor = banco.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM Produtos"
        result = self.banco.execute(query)
        for row_number in enumerate(result):
            if row_number[0] == self.listaprodutos.currentRow():
                data = row_number[1]
                Idprod = data[0]
                Nome2 = self.produtotext.text()
                Quant2 = self.estoquetext.text()
                Preco2 = self.precocustotext.text()
                Valor2 = self.precovendatext.text()
                Forn2 = self.fornecedorcomboBox.currentText()
                if Nome2 !='':
                    self.banco.execute(f"UPDATE Produtos SET Nome='{Nome2}' WHERE Id={Idprod}")
                if Quant2 != '':
                    self.banco.execute(f"UPDATE Produtos SET Quant='{Quant2}' WHERE Id={Idprod}")
                if Valor2 != '':
                    self.banco.execute ( f"UPDATE Produtos SET Valor='{Valor2}' WHERE Id={Idprod}" )
                if Preco2 != '':
                    self.banco.execute( f"UPDATE Produtos SET Preco='{Preco2}' WHERE Id={Idprod}" )
                if Forn2 != '':
                    self.banco.execute( f"UPDATE Produtos SET Forn='{Forn2}' WHERE Id={Idprod}" )
                self.banco.commit()
                self.LoadDatabase()
                self.limparcampos ( )
```

Tomei com base a resposta do Ruben Borges que me mostrou o caminho a seguir.